# Add note to clock entry when moving item to DONE

Tags: org-mode

For my Org buffer, I configured `#+STARTUP: lognoteclock-out` for adding notes to my logbook entries when clocking out, which basically works fine.  However, when the clock is stopped due to the item being marked as DONE (since `org-clock-out-when-done` is enabled as well), I am *not* asked for a log message.  Is there a way to make this happen?

Of course it would work if I clocked out first and marked the item as DONE in a separate step afterwards, but this would somewhat defeat the purpose of `org-clock-out-when-done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Ask for a note when you mark an item `DONE`, which is the simplest option:

```lisp
(setq org-log-done 'note)
```

- check the appropiate hook to track the desired state change, catch the condition you want, and execute what you want. It could be, for example, using  [org-after-todo-state-change-hook](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-after-todo-state-change-hook).

Also, take a look to the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html#Tracking-TODO-state-changes).

Comment: I will go for the hook, thank you!